# Exercício de VisuAlg Resolvido :: Queria dicas de como melhora-lo

Tags: visualg

**Descrição**

Precisava-se obter alguns dados, que podemos verificar abaixo:

- Relacionar o item;
- Código da cidade;
- Número de veículos de passeio;
- Número de acidentes de trânsito com vítimas;

Desejava-se saber ainda:

- Qual o maior e o menor índice de acidentes de trânsito e a que cidades pertencem;
- Qual a média de veículos nas cidades juntas;
- Qual a média de acidentes de trânsito nas cidades com menos de 2000 veículos de passeio.

Resolvi desta forma:

```
    var
    codcidade1,codcidade2,codcidade3:caractere
    numveicid1,numveicid2,numveicid3:inteiro
    opcao:inteiro
    acvit1,acvit2,acvit3:inteiro
    mediaacidentes,mediaveiculos:real
    inicio
    opcao<-0
    escreval(":::IBGE::::")
    escreva("Código da 1° cidade: ")
    leia(codcidade1)
    escreva("Qual a quantidade de veículos de passeio da 1° Cidade:")
    leia(numveicid1)
    escreva("Quantidade de acidentes de transito com vítima na 1° cidade:")
    leia(acvit1)
    limpatela
    escreva("Código da 2° cidade: ")
    leia(codcidade2)
    escreva("Qual a quantidade de veículos de passeio da 2° Cidade:")
    leia(numveicid2)
    escreva("Quantidade de acidentes de transito com vítima na 2° cidade:")
    leia(acvit2)
    limpatela
    escreva("Código da 3° cidade: ")
    leia(codcidade3)
    escreva("Qual a quantidade de veículos de passeio da 3° Cidade:")
    leia(numveicid3)
    escreva("Quantidade de acidentes de transito com vítima na 3° cidade:")
    leia(acvit3)
    limpatela

    se((acvit1 > acvit2) e (acvit1 > acvit3)) entao
         escreval(acvit1," maior indice de acidentes de transito, pertencentes a cidade de codigo ",codcidade1)
       senao
            se((acvit2 > acvit1) e (acvit2 > acvit3)) entao
             escreval(acvit2," maior indice de acidentes de transito, pertencentes a cidade de codigo ",codcidade2)
             senao
                  escreval(acvit3," maior indice de acidentes de transito, pertencentes a cidade de codigo ",codcidade3)
             fimse
    fimse
    se((acvit1 < acvit2) e (acvit1 < acvit3)) entao
         escreval(acvit1," menor indice de acidentes de transito, pertencentes a cidade de codigo ",codcidade1)
       senao
            se((acvit2 < acvit1) e (acvit2 < acvit3)) entao
             escreval(acvit2," menor indice de acidentes de transito, pertencentes a cidade de codigo ",codcidade2)
             senao
                  escreval(acvit3," menor indice de acidentes de transito, pertencentes a cidade de codigo ",codcidade3)
             fimse
    fimse
    escreval()
    mediaveiculos<-(numveicid1+numveicid2+numveicid3)/3
    escreval("A média de veículos nas cidades é ",mediaveiculos)
    escreval()
    se((numveicid1<2000) e (numveicid2<2000) e (numveicid3<2000)) entao
       mediaacidentes <- (acvit1+acvit2+acvit3)/3
       senao
           se((numveicid1<2000) e (numveicid2<2000)) entao
           mediaacidentes <- (acvit1+acvit2)/2
           senao
               se((numveicid1<2000) e (numveicid3<2000)) entao
               mediaacidentes <- (acvit1+acvit3)/2
               senao
                   se((numveicid2<2000) e (numveicid3<2000)) entao
                   mediaacidentes <- (acvit1+acvit3)/2
                   senao
                       se(numveicid1<2000) entao
                       mediaacidentes <-acvit1
                       senao
                          se(numveicid2<2000) entao
                          mediaacidentes <-acvit2
                          senao
                          mediaacidentes <-acvit3
                          fimse
                       fimse
                   fimse
               fimse
           fimse
       fimse

       escreval("a média de acidentes de trânsito nas cidades ")
       escreval("com menos de 2000 veículos de passeio é:",mediaacidentes)
    fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Certamente o uso de vetores tornará seu código muito mais genérico, pois não terá que definir novas variáveis se quiser tratar mais cidades e não apenas estas três. Imagine se tivesse que tratar 200 cidades.

Comment: No trecho `codcidade1,codcidade2,codcidade3:caractere` pq não faz uma matriz? 1 ate 3 e  insere dinamicamente o nome das cidades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira para tratar especificamente seu problema, para um número indeterminado de cidades, é:

```
algoritmo "Exercício"
var
    codcidade, codcidademaior, codcidademenor: caractere
    numveic, numveicmaior, numveicmenor, qtdtotalveic: inteiro
    n, n2000: inteiro
    outra: caractere
    acvit, acvitmaior, acvitmenor, qtdacid2000: inteiro
    mediaacidentes2000, mediaveiculos: real
inicio
    qtdtotalveic <- 0
    qtdacid2000 <- 0
    n2000 <- 0
    n <- 1
    repita
        escreva("Código da ", n, "ª cidade: ")
        leia(codcidade)
        escreva("Qual a quantidade de veículos de passeio da ", n, "ª cidade: ")
        leia(numveic)
        escreva("Quantidade de acidentes de transito com vítimas na ", n, "ª cidade: ")
        leia(acvit)
        se (n = 1) entao
            codcidademenor <- codcidade
            numveicmenor <- numveic
            acvitmenor <- acvit
            codcidademaior <- codcidade
            numveicmaior <- numveic
            acvitmaior <- acvit
        senao
            se (acvit < acvitmenor) entao
                codcidademenor <- codcidade
                numveicmenor <- numveic
                acvitmenor <- acvit
            fimse
            se (acvit > acvitmaior) entao
                codcidademaior <- codcidade
                numveicmaior <- numveic
                acvitmaior <- acvit
            fimse
        fimse
        qtdtotalveic <- qtdtotalveic + numveic
        se (numveic < 2000) entao
            qtdacid2000 <- qtdacid2000 + numveic
            n2000 <- n2000 + 1
        fimse
        n <- n + 1
        escreva("Outra cidade [S/N]: ")
        leia(outra)
    ate ((outra = "n") ou (outra = "N"))
    escreval("Maior índice de acidentes de trânsito: ", acvitmaior, " na cidade: ", codcidademaior)
    escreval("Menor índice de acidentes de trânsito: ", acvitmenor, " na cidade: ", codcidademenor)
    mediaveiculos <- qtdtotalveic / n
    escreval("Média de veículos em todas as cidades: ", mediaveiculos)
    mediaacidentes2000 <- qtdacid2000 / n2000
    escreval("Média de acidentes de trânsito nas cidades com menos de 2000 veículos de passeio: ", mediaacidentes2000)
fimalgoritmo
```